# How to make Outlook/Office365 suggest and/or enforce a particular homonymous recipient?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

A newly hired colleague came in recently, who has the same name as another colleague (who has an entirely different role and job, and works in a different department).

Our corporate email addresses are based on the name of the person, and now Outlook resolves two addresses:

```
j.smith@corporate.com     (pre-existing)
john.smith@corporate.com  (new colleague)
```

I need to communicate heavily with the new colleague, but I mis-pick the address in the auto-complete every other email I send. The other colleague doesn't really complain and understands but the need for constant double-cheking is annoying.

Is there any way (rules, etc) to instruct Outlook to at least notify me when I use the "incorrect" address and point out I should use the other one ? Some kind of automation to replace one address with the other would also be acceptable at the moment.

Comment: Using the built-in option in Outlook, you may create a rule to defer delivery of the messages so you can have some time to double check the recipient email addresses. If you want to get a prompt when using the incorrect address, you may have to use VBA code. See the link below for reference: https://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/prevent-sending-messages-to-wrong-email-address/

Comment: @YukiSun that page didn't come up during my googling, I'll take a look